# how to style text in the table calendar

Tags: flutter

> the result i want
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAnE2.png)
>
> reality
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TJVM.png)
>
> TableCalendar => table_calendar: ^3.0.6

```
my code :

headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
    formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 10),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    ),
    titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      color: Color(0XFF1F2024),
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
    titleTextFormatter: (date, locale) {
      final month = DateFormat.MMMM(locale).format(date);
      final years = DateFormat.y(locale).format(date);
      return '$month\n$years';
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please specify more details about the package name and share the UI snap of what you are trying to achieve and what you have achieved till now

Comment: i just changed it @Prashant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `calendarBuilders` to achieve that one

```
CalendarBuilders(headerTitleBuilder: (context, day) { 
  // add your code here 
})
```

and in TableCalendar

```
 TableCalendar(calendarBuilders: _calendarBuilders);
```